# I don't know how to make my game response system work

Tags: java, if-statement

Basically I have this code, and I want to make it so that when `awnserF = awnser6`, both players lose.  I have no idea how to do that.  I want to accomplish this while maintaining the fact that when `awnserF>awnser6` player one wins.

```
System.out.println("  ");
if (awnserF > awnser6) {
    System.out.println("PLAYER ONE wins!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("PLAYER TWO wins!");
}

if (awnserF = awnser6) {
    System.out.println("You both lose!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
System.out.println("  ");


if (awnserF>awnser6){
System.out.println("PLAYER ONE wins!");
 }
 else if (answerF<answer6) {
System.out.println("PLAYER TWO wins!");
}

else {
System.out.println("You both lose!");
}


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `==` when comparing. The single `=` operator is for assigning a value to a variable.

You can also do this with and if...else if...else structure.

```
if (awnserF > awnser6){
    System.out.println("PLAYER ONE wins!");
}
else if (awnserF < awnser6) {
    System.out.println("PLAYER TWO wins!");
}
else { // (awnserF == awnser6)
    System.out.println("You both lose!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `=` to check if the choices are equal, when it should actually be `==`. This should work.

```
if(awnswerF == awnser6){
    System.out.println("You both lose!")
}
else if(awnserF > awnser6){
    System.out.println("PLAYER ONE wins!")
}
else{
    System.out.println("PLAYER TWO wins!")
}
```

But really, who wants to play a game where both players can lose ;)

Answer (score 0):

what about this using `if,elseif,else` structure:

```java
if (awnserF>awnser6){
    System.out.println("PLAYER ONE wins!");
}
else if(awnserF==awnser6){
    System.out.println("You both lose!");
}
else{
    System.out.println("PLAYER TWO wins!");
}
```

Note: there are 2 `==` to compare, 1 `=` is for assignment